# Sub-setting a data frame with [x] vis-a-vis [,x] in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following Data Frame:

```
> head(mortality_data) 
Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack State 
1867    MERITUS MEDICAL CENTER                       17.1    MD 
1868    UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND    MEDICAL CENTER     18.0    MD
...
```

I understand that querying a data frame with[,x] returns *a list* vis-à-vis querying with [x] returns a *subset* of a given *data frame*

```
> class(mortality_data[,2])
[1] "numeric"
> class(mortality_data[2])
[1] "data.frame"
```

When I subset this data frame with either:

```
mortality_data <- mortality_data[mortality_data[2]!="Not Available",]
```

or

```
mortality_data <- mortality_data[mortality_data[,2]!="Not Available",]
```

I get exactly the same class (data frame) and a subset of my data which is:

```
> head(mortality_data)
Hospital.Name Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack State
1867                MERITUS MEDICAL CENTER                                                      17.1    MD
1868 UNIVERSITY OF MARYLAND MEDICAL CENTER                                                      18.0    MD
…
> class(mortality_data)
[1] "data.frame"
...
> class(mortality_data)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Question: when would sub-setting a data frame with [x] (which is a *list* object) vis-à-vis [,x] (a column within the *data frame*) make a difference?

Thanks

Comment: But, when you do a comparison `!=`, it no longer is a `data.frame`, it would be a matrix (vector with some dim attributes), for the first case, and in second, it is a vector.

Comment: thanks, @akrun. how do I see that in code? when I attempted queries below, I kept getting identical comparisons. 
```mortality_data_1 <- outcomedata[,c(2,11,7)] 
mortality_data_2 <- outcomedata[,c(2,11,7)] 
library(compare) > comparison <- compare(mortality_data_1,mortality_data_2,coerce=FALSE) 
comparison TRUE <br/>difference <- data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(mortality_data_1),function(i)setdiff(mortality_data_1[,i],comparison$tM[,i])))
colnames(difference) <- colnames(mortality_data_1)
difference 
...
<0 rows>```

Comment: you can create an `if/else` condition or specify `drop = FALSE]` so that it would always return a logical matrix instead of a vector

Comment: @akrun, may i please ask you for a code sample to test that? thanks